.profile being sourced multiple times
I was checking my environmental variable $PATH, and I found that it contains duplicate paths. The reason seems to be that my ~/.profile has been sourced four times.
I really couldn't figure out why this is the case, so I added
# Guard against multiple sourcing
[ -z "$PROFILE_SOURCED" ] && export PROFILE_SOURCED=1 || return 0

However this does not seem to work.
This does not affect how my system works, but I am curious why this is happening and why I cannot stop it.

return 0 outside of a function won't stop the sourcing of the file, you need exit 0; can you test with exit 0 and make sure ~/.bashrc is not sourcing ~/.profile? Can you post the contents of ~/.profile?

Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile files. If you have a ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login, show us those as well.

I have just realized the issue is that each time I log out from a Desktop Environment and log in again, .profile is sourced.
To avoid modifying $PATH unnecessarily, I found the following script works.
# Function to add a directory to PATH if it's not already there
add_to_path() {
    local dir="$1"
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        case ":${PATH}:" in
            *:"$dir":*)
                ;;
            *)
                export PATH="$dir:$PATH"
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}

add_to_path "$HOME/bin"
add_to_path "$HOME/.local/bin"
add_to_path "$HOME/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux"
add_to_path "$HOME/.elan/bin"



The function add_to_path checks if the path to add is already in $PATH and avoid adding it again.

@kos Actually, the pattern in the case statement with explicit colons works for first or last positions too. Fighting the DE is an ancient problem, but usually, the issue is that when you pop up a terminal, it isn't a login term and hasn't sourced the .profile. User efforts to counter this defect lead to awful things like putting environment changes in .bashrc or explicitly making the DE term invocation a login -- easily leading to duplicate entries in things like PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

@ubfan1 You're right, I mistakenly assumed they were comparing the directory they were trying to add (with the added colons) to the unmodified PATH, I didn't notice the colons around PATH. My bad; I still mantain the point that it doesn't make too much sense that the same shell would be sourcing ~/.profile over and over (across different logins) as it's implied here, and rather the issue is likely in other dotfiles, likely some sort of ~/.bashrc / ~/.profile loop as you're suggesting (I'm not saying those are the files involved, perhaps it's other dotfiles sourced by the shell)
